# Display lag on external monitor connected to ThinkPad Dock with Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, docking-station

I have a **ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock** connected to a **ThinkPad T14** laptop with **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** and a DELL external monitor. I had no display on my external screen until I installed the following driver:
[DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu (5.4.1)](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu). Since then, display is working but **response time is very slow**. Any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with X11 version shipped in 20.04. There was a patch apparently but it's no longer available. An updated X11 with the patch is available in 21.04.

I solved it without upgrading by using Wayland instead of X11. Wayland is actually awesome now and I haven't noticed any issues yet. Wayland is also the new default in 22.04, unless you are using an Nvidia GPU.

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349541/displaylink-laggy-displayport-screens-in-ubuntu-20-04-2-tls-kde-plasma-ryzen-470

Comment: Thanks for your message. I don't have the dock anymore, so I cannot test your solution. Hope it will help other folks.